# How to set 2 buttons trigger from same event?

Tags: javascript

The question is in the code snippet. Which is :
*Is it possible when $("#b").click event happen, it change button A too? Button A & B are in different function/class. How should I pass this event from wrapperB to wrapperA to do something too when $("#b").click event happened?*

```js
function wrapperA(){

  function init(){
    // if B button clicked.
    // change A button html text to "A" or "a" (action to do in actual is different from wrapperB)
  }

   return {
     init: init
   };
}

function wrapperB(){

   function init() {
    $("#b").click(function() {
     if($("#text").html() === "UpperCase"){
      $("#b").html("b");
     } else {
     $("#b").html("B");
     }
     
     $("#text").html(
       ($("#text").html() === "UpperCase") ?
       "LowerCase" :
       "UpperCase"
     );
    });

   }
   
   return {
     init: init
   };
}

// is it possible when $("#b").click event happen, it change button A too? Button A & B are in different function/class. How should I pass this event from wrapperB to wrapperA to do something too when $("#b").click event happened?
wrapperA().init();  
wrapperB().init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapperA">
<button id="a">A</button>
</div>

<div id="wrapperB">
<button id="b">B</button>
<div id="text">UpperCase</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the usecase here. Why the wrapper functions?

Comment: Hmm basically wrapper A is my webpage topbar, the button A is a collapse/expand button (< to collapse, > to expand).        
Wrapper B is my webpage sidebar where it has a button on the sidebar right border to collapse/expand.       
I can handle toggle wrapper A button icon by getting initial state of sidebar. then just toggle the button A FontAwesome class. The problem is how ButtonB click event can inform wrapper A to change ButtonA icon? So the wrapper is to segregate the sidebar / topbar creation/events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to dispatch a custom event from the buttons on-click function to the others on-click function.

Something like this:

```js
// wrapperA

function init() {
  buttonAction();
  window.addEventListener('onButtonB', buttonAction);
}

function buttonAction() {
  // do button action
  let buttonEvent = new CustomEvent('onButtonA');
  window.dispatchEvent(buttonEvent);
}
```

and for the other button:

```js
// wrapperB

function init() {
  buttonAction();
  window.addEventListener('onButtonA', buttonAction);
}

function buttonAction() {
  // do button action
  let buttonEvent = new CustomEvent('onButtonB');
  window.dispatchEvent(buttonEvent);
}
```

The easiest way would be to just use one function to change both buttons and add them to the click event of both buttons.

Comment: Forget the last sentence... I have not read your comment...

Comment: Thanks. This is the approach I want. I hope I can do it in one function too but from what I see, I don't allow to do that

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to call the other function on click of B.

```js
function wrapperA() {

  function init() {
    if ($("#text").html() === "UpperCase") {
     $("#a").html("a");
    }
    else {
      $("#a").html("A");
    }
  }

  return {
    init: init
  };
}

function wrapperB() {

  function init() {
    $("#b").click(function() {
      // Call the other function...
      wrapperA().init();
      if ($("#text").html() === "UpperCase") {
        $("#b").html("b");
      } else {        
        $("#b").html("B");
      }

      $("#text").html(
        ($("#text").html() === "UpperCase") ?
        "LowerCase" :
        "UpperCase"
      );
    });
  }
  
  return {
    init: init
  };
}

wrapperB().init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapperA">
  <button id="a">A</button>
</div>

<div id="wrapperB">
  <button id="b">B</button>
  <div id="text">UpperCase</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think of this too but not suit my usecase because my code initialize wrapperB then only wrapperA. In fact, wrapperA relied a lot function from wrapperB. So I need to run wrapperB first.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to understand your usecase. Perhaps you meant this?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#b").click(function() {
    let aText = $("#a").text();
    let bText = $("#b").text();
    const func = $("#text").text();
    aText = aText["to" + func]();
    bText = bText["to" + func]();
    $("#a").text(aText)
    $("#b").text(bText)
    $("#text").text(func === "UpperCase" ? "LowerCase" : "UpperCase");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapperA">
  <button id="a">A</button>
</div>

<div id="wrapperB">
  <button id="b">B</button>
  <div id="text">LowerCase</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is ok only if the 2 buttons is in same function. My problem is I wouldn't know the button A from wrapperB and vice versa. ParadoxonModding has the solution suit my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

you can use common `class` to trigger the following change.

```
<div id="wrapperA">
<button id="a" class="btn-txt">A</button>
</div>

<div id="wrapperB">
<button id="b">B</button>
<div id="text" class="btn-txt">UpperCase</div>
</div>

$("#b").on('click', function(){
     if($("#text").html() === "UpperCase"){
        $('.btn-txt').map(function(i,v){$(v).html($(v).text().toUpperCase())});
     } else {
        $('.btn-txt').map(function(i,v){$(v).html($(v).text().toLowerCase())});
     }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not my usecase. Because button A & button B will do differently at the onclick event. So I can't commonly use class to perform the action. Yes I can then later switch button ID but the code doesn't look nice anymore.

Comment: just to check and change the text you can use the common `class`. else you can manage or trigger the click using different `id` attribute